# intellij have introduce constant be private not public

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts

In Intellij IDEA 11.1.2, when using the refactor shortcut to Introduce a Constant, it always makes **public static final** constant, whereas I generally prefer to default to **private**.
In older versions of Intellij, I'm pretty sure that I had the option of setting **private** as the default.
Does anyone know if there still exists an option to default to **private** for the Introduce Constant refactor option rather than having to afterwards go to the declaration and edit the **public** to **private**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it (idea 12).

To introduce private constants by default do the following:

- Disable [in-place mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/general.html#in_place_refactorings)  (File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> uncheck "Enable in-place mode")
- Try to introduce something (You will see a refactor dialog). Select "private" in that dialog
- Enable in-place mode
- Enjoy private constants

Answer (score 4):

ah, never mind, I see. You have to press command-alt-C again to get the old dialog. Grrr. The short cut is getting longer....

Comment: You may, at one point, have checked a "Do not show again" option in the dialog which will make it re-use whatever settings you had selected at that time to be your defaults. Try looking through the settings to re-enable the dialog which will let you adjust whether public or private is the default.

Comment: If someone ever has this problem, and you want to reset a dialog, simply press the shortcut to activate it + SHIFT. The original dialog will appear, and you can change your settings at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but as of now there is an easier way to get the desired result than the accepted Answer:

You can simply press the shortcut to introduce a constant twice to get refactoring dialog and select private there once.

From now on pressing the shortcut will always introduce a private constant.

The same procedure can then be used to switch back to public. No need to click through the setting each time.